# Combine blender with other free programs to make films

Tags: workflow

I'm a 13 year old who aspires to be a filmmaker, but I don't have money to spend on software. Luckily, Blender is free, and so is HitFilm Express 2017. I know Express doesn't support 3d models, so is there a way I could still use both programs?

Comment: Well, you could use Blender for the bigger VFX stuff and HitFilm for the small stuff. For example, if you wanted to have someone shooting a gun you could use blender for the gun itself, and once you successfully rendered that into the footage you could go into HitFilm and add in muzzle fire. I don't know a lot about HitFilm, but I can see that being a good use for it.

Comment: Free programs worth exploring to make films: Resolve (for editing and color correction). Fusion (for compositing). Natron (open source compositing).

Comment: The answer is yes. This is how most film workflows work, nobody really does 3D stuff directly in editing or compositing software unless its absolutely necessary or convenient for some reason.

Personally what i find useful is to watch tutorials from other more common software like After Effects or Maya and then try to recreate in Blender with the toolset that you have. Most of common techniques still work, they are just named differently in the different programs. 

Another thing to consider is that Blender does by itself have an editor and compositor integrated (but they are hit and miss)

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a little of what you want to do, but your workflow will usually be to generate video sequences in blender and the export them to the video format you need to edit them in hitfilm. You dont need to support 3D model in HitFilm since blender can export video sequences.

For an animation movie, you just render your sequence and use it as such in hitfilm.

For special effect, blender has a lot of tools that allows to integrate 3D objects in a video,camera tracking, green screen masking, ... 
You will import a video in blender (a movie sequence) and add 3D item in the scene, using [camera tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY) to keep the orientation of the blender camera consistent with the "real life "camera used to make this sequence. 
You will use [masking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PZ_cxjxexM) to keep a part of your real life object to integrate it in a 3D scene. 
You will use [object tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuNew5QmPWU) to identify the position of a real life element to attach a 3D object, like a gun to a hand.

Blender can do all of this so the choice of HitFilm won't restrict you for the 3D parts. Only for the editing/compositing part.

Comment: I'd recommend rendering to an image sequence, using png files can keep the alpha to help compositing in hitfilm that you will loose with video files.